# HttpWebRequest to upload docx file to curl python from c#

Tags: c#, python, httpwebrequest, docx

This is what i use to call from ubuntu:

`curl -X POST http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX -F 'file[]=@file1.docx' -i`

I want to execute this from c#.

Note: I tried other stackoverflow answers/solutions, but i always get :
`internal server error : 505`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could call it successfully using following code.

```
public static string HttpUploadFile(string file)
{
    string paramName = "file[]";
    string[] result = null;
    string url = "http://192.168.XX.XX:XXXX";
    string contenttype_xlsx = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    string contenttype_pptx = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
    string contenttype_docx = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";         
    string contentType = "";

    switch (Path.GetExtension(file))
    {
        case ".docx":
            contentType = contenttype_docx;
            break;

        case ".pptx":
            contentType = contenttype_pptx;
            break;

        default:
            contentType = contenttype_xlsx;
            break;
    }            

    string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.KeepAlive = true;
    wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

    rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

    string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
    string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, Path.GetFileName(file), contentType);
    byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
    rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fileStream.Close();

    byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
    rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
    rs.Close();

    WebResponse wresp = null;
    try
    {
        wresp = wr.GetResponse();
        Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2, Encoding.UTF8);
        string s = reader2.ReadToEnd();

        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(s);        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (wresp != null)
        {
            wresp.Close();
            wresp = null;
        }
        throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        wr = null;
    }

    return obj.ToString();
}
```